# Windows phone 8.1 Textblock width to Fill

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone, textblock

I want to create the layout as shown in the following image's first section.
But with the code attached, I can only get the layout output as show in the bottom section of the image attached.

[image]

```
    <ListView Grid.Row="1"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
              Margin="0,20,0,0">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="40" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <TextBlock TextWrapping="NoWrap"
                                   TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"
                                   Grid.Column="0"
                                   Text="{Binding Name}"
                                   Style="{ThemeResource ListViewItemTextBlockStyle}" />

                        <Image Grid.Column="1"
                               Source="image.png"/>

                    </Grid>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the StackPanel in the DataTemplate - the Grid you have is enough for this.

Also, in order to get the items to stretch, define a simple ListView.ItemContainerStyle in your ListView:

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

So, full code:

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
          Margin="0,20,0,0">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="40" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <TextBlock TextWrapping="NoWrap"
                           TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"
                           Grid.Column="0"
                           Text="{Binding Name}"
                           Style="{ThemeResource ListViewItemTextBlockStyle}" />

                <Image Grid.Column="1"
                       Source="image.png"/>

            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
<ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
```

instead of Width="*"